# Running a Servlet in a Maven Project using Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

So I have installed Tomcat and that is working just fine. Currently I’m using Maven in Eclipse for a project. I want to run a servlet on tomcat with a maven project, how do I do that? It’s not as easy as just putting the files in the tomcat/webapps folder.

Comment: Are you talking about how to deploy your finished servlet? Or are you asking about how, in development, to run your servlet from Eclipse IDE in Tomcat with debugging enabled? (a) Edit to clarify. (b) Either way, the topic has almost certainly been addressed already on Stack Overflow. Always search before posting.

Comment: `mvn package` the project and deploy the .war in the webapps folder, also don't forget to add packaging war in pom.xml